# Is there a tidy way to ignore few rows and use summarise function?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like:

| id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | A | 1 |
| x1 | A | 2 |
| x1 | A | 3 |
| x1 | B | 2 |
| x1 | B | 4 |
| x1 | B | 6 |
| x1 | C | 1 |
| x1 | C | 3 |
| x1 | C | 5 |

I want to summarise two columns from the above data

1. median of the values for each type and
2. median of the values for all types, but the respective type. i.e., For type-A calculate median of the values for types B and C.

like:

| id | type | median_type_value | median_non_type_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | A | 2 | 3.5 |
| x1 | B | 4 | 2.5 |
| x1 | C | 3 | 2.5 |

I am able to calculate the median_type_value, but not the other one.

Example data/code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(id=c(rep("x1",9)), type=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)), value=c(1,2,3,2,4,6,1,3,5))

df %>% 
group_by(id,type) %>% 
summarise(median_type_value=median(value))
```

Would be great to have some pointers or solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
  reframe(median_type_value = median(value), 
   median_non_type_value = 
   median(df$value[df$type !=cur_group()$type]), .by = c(id, type))
```

-output

```
   id type median_type_value median_non_type_value
1 x1    A                 2                   3.5
2 x1    B                 4                   2.5
3 x1    C                 3                   2.5
```

---

Or with previous versions of `dplyr`

```
df %>%
   group_by(id, type) %>%
   summarise(median_type_value = median(value),
     median_non_type_value =  median(df$value[df$type 
      !=cur_group()$type]), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  id    type  median_type_value median_non_type_value
  <chr> <chr>             <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 x1    A                     2                   3.5
2 x1    B                     4                   2.5
3 x1    C                     3                   2.5
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, 
       {
      tmp <- .SD
     tmp[,.(median_type_value = median(value),
       median_non_type_value = median(tmp$value[tmp$type != .BY])), 
          type]
    }, id]
```

-output

```
    id type median_type_value median_non_type_value
1: x1    A                 2                   3.5
2: x1    B                 4                   2.5
3: x1    C                 3                   2.5
```

Comment: looks neat! Unfortunately, I can't update the dplyr version (using 1.0.7). are you aware of a different possibility?